# How do I get the key of this level?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Hi, 
 I have this problem in query in Firebase. The orderbykey() and orderbychild() doesn't work. How do I query this one?

cheers, thanks in advance.

Code Snippet:

```
    Query mRef = mRootRef.child("Messages").orderByKey().equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
    Query mRef = mRootRef.child("Messages").orderByChild("commWith").equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());
```

[image]

Comment: What have you tried so far ? Please show your code snippet.

Comment: i have tried, orderbychild using the commWith in the firebase but none of it works @KulsDroid

Comment: show your java code

Comment: @RahulChandrabhan, the code snippet is shown in the image

Comment: Please replace both the pictures of code and JSON with their actual textual contents. For the JSON, you can easily get this by clicking the Export JSON link in [your Firebase Database console](https://console.firebase.google.com/project/_/database/data/). Having the JSON and code as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: What is happening when you are using `Query mRef = mRootRef.child("Messages").orderByKey().equalTo(mAuth.getCurrentUser().getUid());`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i have just re design my JSON at firebase like in the image below, so that i could simply get the unique keys per data[image]